# Unity AddComponent Very Inefficient and Slow

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, instantiation, large-data

I have a dataset of almost 120,000 stars and a test dataset of 215 stars (taken from the main dataset) and I am making a program that reads the dataset and plots stars around a 3D Earth model.

1. Dataset is read and info are stored in multiple lists (in a singleton script)
2. Simulation script then reads the lists (Singleton is destroyed to make program more efficient):

```
void listStars()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < (StarDataBank.Instance.NumOfStars))
    {
        int primaryID = int.Parse(StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDID[i]);
        string properName = StarDataBank.Instance.StarName[i];
        string HIPID = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDHIP[i];
        string HDID = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDHD[i];
        string HRID = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDHR[i];
        string GLID = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDGL[i];
        string BFID = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDBF[i];
        decimal rightAscension = Convert.ToDecimal(StarDataBank.Instance.StarRA[i]);
        decimal declination = Convert.ToDecimal(StarDataBank.Instance.StarDec[i]);
        decimal Mag;
        decimal CI;
        float scale = 0;
        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;

        Decimal.TryParse((StarDataBank.Instance.StarMag[i]), out Mag);
        Decimal.TryParse((StarDataBank.Instance.StarCI[i]), out CI);

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("dynamicSize") == 1)
        {
            if (Mag < -1)
            {
                scale = 77.5f;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Mag > -1 && Mag <= 5)
                {
                    scale = 52.5f;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Mag > 5 && Mag <= 10)
                    {
                        scale = 32.5f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Mag > 10 && Mag <= 15)
                        {
                            scale = 17.5f;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Mag > 15 && Mag <= 20)
                            {
                                scale = 7.5f;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Mag > 20 && Mag <= 25)
                                {
                                    scale = 2.5f;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            scale = 20;
        }
        StartCoroutine(placeStars(primaryID, properName, HIPID, HDID, HRID, GLID, BFID, rightAscension, declination, Mag, CI, scale));
        i++;
    }
    DestroyImmediate(StarDataBank.Instance.gameObject);
}
```

3. Each star is plotted with this method:

```
    IEnumerator placeStars(int primaryID, string properName, string HIPID, string HDID, string HRID, string GLID, string BFID, decimal rightAscension, decimal declination, decimal magnitude, decimal colourIndex, float scale)
    {
        var thisStar = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabStar, transform.position + getVectors(Convert.ToDecimal(rightAscension), Convert.ToDecimal(declination)), Quaternion.identity);
        thisStar.name = (primaryID).ToString();
        thisStar.transform.parent = StarObject.transform;
        thisStar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
        thisStar.AddComponent<Star>().newStar(primaryID, properName, HIPID, HDID, HRID, GLID, BFID, rightAscension, declination, magnitude, colourIndex);
        yield return null;
    }
```

Using the smaller test dataset with only 215 stars, I am able to attach the Star class to each Instantiated star.

But with the large full dataset with ~120k stars, the Unity Editor just hangs after the play button is pressed. When I comment out this line: `thisStar.AddComponent<Star>().newStar(...);` The program works as intended, each star is plotted in the scene, the only thing is that the Star class isn't getting attached to each newly instantiated star.

This means that the AddComponent function is not playing well with my code, especially when the large dataset is being used.

Is there a more efficient way of attaching the Star class to each instantiated star GameObject?

Also, does it make a difference when I destroy the singleton after I've finished using it? And does it make a difference that I've used IEnumerator to instantiate?

EDIT: Here's the Star class:

```
public class Star : MonoBehaviour
{


    Simulation simulationInstance;


    public int primaryID;  // primary key                                      NEEDS TO BE SET
    public string properName;  // some stars have names                        NEEDS TO BE SET
    public string HIPID;   // ID of star from Hipparcos catalogue              NEEDS TO BE SET
    public string HDID;    // ID of star from Henry Draper catalogue           NEEDS TO BE SET
    public string HRID;    // ID of star from Harvard Revised catalogue        NEEDS TO BE SET
    public string GLID;    // ID of star from Gliese catalogue                 NEEDS TO BE SET
    public string BFID;    // ID of star from BayerFlamsteed catalogue         NEEDS TO BE SET
    public decimal rightAscension; // right ascension of star                  NEEDS TO BE SET
    public decimal declination;    // declination of star                      NEEDS TO BE SET
    public decimal magnitude;  // magnitude of the star                        NEEDS TO BE SET
    public decimal colourIndex;    // colour index of the star                 NEEDS TO BE SET
    public int scale;  // size of the sphere that will represent the star      AUTOMATICALLY SET
    public int red;    // red colour (0-255)                                   AUTOMATICALLY SET
    public int green;  // green colour (0-255)                                 AUTOMATICALLY SET  
    public int blue;   // blue colour (0-255)                                  AUTOMATICALLY SET
    public double x;   //                                                      AUTOMATICALLY SET
    public double y;   //                                                      AUTOMATICALLY SET
    public double z;   //                                                      AUTOMATICALLY SET

    void Start()
    {
        simulationInstance = FindObjectOfType<Simulation>();
    }

    public void newStar(int primaryID, string properName, string HIPID, string HDID, string HRID, string GLID, string BFID, decimal rightAscension, decimal declination, decimal magnitude, decimal colourIndex)
    {
        this.primaryID = primaryID;
        this.properName = properName;
        this.HIPID = HIPID;
        this.HDID = HDID;
        this.HRID = HRID;
        this.GLID = GLID;
        this.BFID = BFID;
        this.rightAscension = rightAscension;
        this.declination = declination;
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
        this.colourIndex = colourIndex;

    }

    public void tellStarInfoPanel()
    {
        simulationInstance.starInfoPanelManager(primaryID, properName, HIPID, HDID, HRID, GLID, BFID, rightAscension, declination, magnitude, colourIndex);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have made listStars() a coroutine and placeStars() a normal method

```
    public void placeStars(int primaryID, string properName, string HIPID, string HDID, string HRID, string GLID, string BFID, decimal rightAscension, decimal declination, decimal magnitude, decimal colourIndex, float scale)
    {
        var thisStar = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabStar, transform.position + getVectors(Convert.ToDecimal(rightAscension), Convert.ToDecimal(declination)), Quaternion.identity);
        thisStar.name = (primaryID).ToString();
        thisStar.transform.parent = StarObject.transform;
        thisStar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
        thisStar.GetComponent<Star>().newStar(primaryID, properName, HIPID, HDID, HRID, GLID, BFID, rightAscension, declination, magnitude, colourIndex);
        starsRendered++;  
    }
```

Comment: Using a coroutine here has no added value, since all the code in it runs at once, then it stalls for a frame and move on. So you could use a normal void method. If your program tends to slow down, maybe you could consider loading only the stars that are relevant, for instance the visible ones or close ones. You could use a coroutine to create then over time, so instead of creating them all in one run, you create first 200, then yield return, next 200 and so on. It will take a few seconds but you are able to use the app in the meanwhile.

Comment: So what I'd do, I'd first run and create 200 of the stars that are within certain radius, those not created go in a collection. Then the next 200 and so on until initial is empty. Once done, same method but with the far collection. Your method would look something like IEnumerator CreateStars(IEnumerable <Star> initial, IEnumerable<Star> nextBatch, float radius); initial is the collection to run and nextBatch is the collection to place far items. Each time, nextBatch becomes initial. Run this until initial is empty.

Comment: `FindObjectOfType<>()` is pretty heavy too, eliminate it. This looks like a perfect use case for ECS, I'd take a look into it as Andrew suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a more efficient way of attaching the Star class to each instantiated star GameObject?

> Yes. Your Star prefab should already have the component `Star`
>   attached. Then you can instantiate it as `var thisStar =
>   (Star)Instantiate(prefabStar, transform.position +
>   getVectors(Convert.ToDecimal(rightAscension),
>   Convert.ToDecimal(declination)), Quaternion.identity);`, avoiding the
>   AddComponent step.

Also, does it make a difference when I destroy the singleton after I've finished using it?

> No. It's not consuming any processing, you will just free some memory.

And does it make a difference that I've used IEnumerator to instantiate?

> Only if you want to instantiate the objects over multiple frames, as
>   I've shown below.

Some things you can improve

1. Instantiate the stars over multiple frames: For this you must turn your `listStars`method into a Coroutine, making the return type an IEnumerator and using `yield return placeStars(primaryID, properName, HIPID, HDID, HRID, GLID, BFID, rightAscension, declination, Mag, CI, scale)`. You might want to instantiate multiple stars on the same frame, or it might take some time!
2. Your Star `Start` method becomes increasingly expensive at every star instantiated, it's better to pass it as an argument to the `placeStars` method, acquiring it only once before the loop stars.
3. You don't need to get `dynamicSize` from `PlayerPrefs` at every iteration. Store it before the loop starts. The same goes for the singleton instance. Cache it before the loop starts and use the cached reference.

Pseudo code example:

```
IEnumerator listStars()
{
    var starDataBank = StarDataBank.Instance;
    var dynamicSize = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("dynamicSize");
    var simulationInstance = FindObjectOfType<Simulation>();
    var starsPerFrame = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < starDataBank.NumOfStars; i++)
    {
        // do your stuff
        for (int j = 0; j < starsPerFrame; j++)
            placeStars(simulationInstance, primaryID, properName, HIPID, HDID, HRID, GLID, BFID, rightAscension, declination, Mag, CI, scale));
        yield return null;
    }
    DestroyImmediate(starDataBank.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, used IEnumerator with theStars method and now Unity doesn't hang anymore. I can also see the stars being instantiated one by one. Quick note, the for loop which places the stars, when stars per frame is increased, the same stars are being instantiated. Is there a way to instantiate multiple gameobjects at the same time?

Comment: That's strange, if possible post your code here. Probably you are returning the `placeStars` routine. That would make only one star be instantiated per frame.
Would make more sense to turn `placeStars` into a normal method, returning void.

Comment: When using the code above, the variable named i inside of the loop outer loop apparently can't be declared in that scope.

Comment: Oh sorry, the inner loop should use another variable name, like j. I'll update the code for you.

Comment: Thanks, but if I set starsPerFrame to something like 2 wouldn’t that just instantiate 2 identical stars?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That "do your stuff" part should be inside the inner loop and the parameters adjusted accordingly.
Anyway, the point is that everything that happens before `yield return null` are executed on the N frame, everything after it, on the N+1 frame, and by distributing the load over multiple frames you'll probably prevent Unity from hanging.

Answer (score 0):

If you think AddComponent() is computationally too heavy, it would be wise to have a closer look at Start component or even better running a Unity's profiler tool which should exactly pinpoint the culprit.

Also do your Star has to be a Component? Maybe you can go around this problem by simply utilising OO techniques.

Comment: Unfortunately all of Unity just hangs, and I don't think profiler works. Unless profiler doesn't hang with Unity. Please expand on Start component.

Comment: Also, I'm running Unity 2019.2.12f1. Do you think I will get a performance increase with a newer version?

Comment: @SidS Make your dataset smaller for testing purposes and then run the profiler, just extrapolate

Comment: Please expand on the OO techniques. I thought adding a class to each star was object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid usage of `AddComponent` in [performance critical code](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Avoid-usage-of-AddComponent-in-performance-critical-code)

Calling `GameObject.AddComponent` is expensive, especially inside a [performance critical context](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Performance-critical-context-and-costly-methods). Each time a component is added, the following must happen:

> 1. Finding the component's script in the script cache, by name. This might also incur allocations if it's not already cached.
> 2. Allocating the memory for the MonoBehaviour.
> 3. Notifying other attached components that a new component has been added. The attached components can perform actions when a known
>      component is added. The amount of work performed here depends on the
>      number and type of attached components. E.g. a rigid body needs to
>      know if a collider is added.
> 4. Running the new component's Awake method. This inspection will highlight calls to AddComponent inside a performance critical context.
>      It will also mark the calling method as expensive, and any usages of
>      the calling method will also receive a performance indicator
>      highlight.

Comment: Could you suggest another way to let me attach a class to a newly instantiated GameObject?

Comment: What does Star component do?

Comment: See original question edit for more details, but in short, the Star class simply takes each stars' details. Details such as different IDs, magnitude, positions, etc...

Comment: @Sids , by design , if its in the game not a tool, why you just make a prefab with all the things you want and just instantiate the prefab?

Comment: @VectorX, I have about 120,000 stars in my full dataset, making a prefab for each star will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that this is not a good use case for Monobehaviour/Component OOP model. You may want consider switching to **preview** [ECS tech stack](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.6/manual/index.html)  for this.
Not long time ago I tested similar case and found out that instancing 100k entities from csv file is doable. In this situation my HDD I/O was the bottleneck and not CPU/memory (opposite of what happens with Monobehaviours). What's more - loading time can be optimized by pre-caching your raw data as memory segments [serialized to binary files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.6/api/Unity.Entities.Serialization.SerializeUtilityHybrid.html).
But I won sugar-coat it - it's much more advanced programming than Monobehaviours and this tech stack is in unstable pre-release state at the moment.

Comment: I've never used ECS, It would be great if you could link me to a guide or perhaps send a snippet of code that explains the usage of ESC.

Comment: General idea is to layout all data in big arrays for every (struct) data type and to stay away from managed (class/object) as much as possible. ECS helps with that at cost of complicating/obfuscating the process for programmer tho.

Comment: But you can take very similar approach without all this. For a start - don't use GameObjects for things that needs to be replicated in thousands, **ever again**. If you need to draw >1e3 stars then create an array of matrices and just render all of them using [Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced.html) every frame (!), done - 0 instantiations even needed.

Comment: This line of thinking would mean reworking your placeStars() method to something array-oriented like [THIS](https://pastebin.com/d1iWnZVR)

Comment: [HERE](https://pastebin.com/j1846sFx) is a example of how to go about rendering them.